# How to make search with filtering in recyclerView(firebase)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search written via order by.
I have 6 buttons (in the future checkboxes) that filter the contents of the view by category.
Buttons are described in a similar way to search.
How to write search and filter correctly in order to synchronize the work of both checkboxes and the search line, so as not to prescribe each script separately.

search code

```
private void search(String s) {
    Query query = ProductsRef.orderByChild("prodName")
            .startAt(s)
            .endAt(s + "\uf8ff");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasChildren())
            {
                arrayList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dss: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    final Products product = dss.getValue(Products.class);
                    arrayList.add(product);
                }
                MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

button code

```
private void SortByCat(String u) {
    Query query = ProductsRef.orderByChild("category").startAt(u).endAt(u +"\uf8ff" );
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasChildren())
            {
                arrayList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dss: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    final Products product = dss.getValue(Products.class);
                    arrayList.add(product);
                }
                MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Search and buttons work separately, and to be honest, I don’t have enough experience to come up with something more concise than going through all the options for using filters with search.

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. --- After that, it'll be easier to help if you debug locally and tell us the results. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.